# Connect Marketing Cloud Journey Builder to Salesforce Sandbox Environment

Tags: marketing-cloud, sandbox, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm wondering if it's possible to connect Marketing Cloud to a Salesforce sandbox environment with the Journey Builder API

Thanks in advance!

-N

Comment: You can certainly use Marketing Cloud Connect with a Sandbox environment, but I don't think this is what you are asking for. Please can you provide additional detail in how you will be using the Journey Builder API? Will you be making requests from Apex, and if so, what will the request do?

Comment: @EliotHarper We will be making requests from apex and the request is pulling in fields from the lead obj into the journey's DE

Comment: I'm still unclear why you would want to use the Journey Builder API and I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Please can you edit your question and provide further information.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible to connect Marketing Cloud's Journey Builder API to a Sandbox. Essentially, you're just treating the Sandbox as a 3rd party system.

I'm assuming you have MC Connector configured and integrated this with the Production environment. This will allow you to create SF Entry Events, SF Object Activity etc.

For the Sandbox, none of these activities will be available... You can create an API Entry Event in Journey Builder. In order to do that, you need to go via the API as you suggest, which means creating API Access Credentials (via Installed Packages in Marketing Cloud).

So while you can connect it, please do not use this as a way to "test" SF Entry Events. SF Entry Events are executed via "Process Builder" whereas your Sandbox API test would execute via APEX Code, which, in the order of execution might yield very different outcomes.